# Visible Binding Based On Bound Object and Model Properties

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I ran in to the unique situation today where I needed to bind the `Visible` property of a button in a `DataGridRow` to be based on both a property of the bound object and of the model backing it.

XAML:

```
<t:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <t:DataGrid.Columns>
        <t:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <t:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Visibility="IsEditable OR IsAdmin"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </t:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </t:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </t:DataGrid.Columns>
</t:DataGrid>
```

Model:

```
class TheModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Whatever> Items { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

Class:

```
class Whatever
{
    public bool IsEditable { get; set; }
}
```

This stumped me. The only concept that I could think might work would be somehow passing the bound object and either the entire model or just the `IsAdmin` property to a static method on a converter or something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot directly use a Boolean for Visibility. You need to use the [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx).

Secondly, about the *OR*, you have different options:

1. Create a readonly property `IsEditableOrAdmin` in `Whatever` which returns the value you want. Drawback: Your `Whatever` will need a back-reference to `TheModel`.
2. Use a MultiBinding and write an [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx). Then, pass *both* values in the MultiBinding. Since `TheModel` is no longer in the DataContext scope at that point, you could use the `ElementName` property of the Binding to refer to a UI element where `TheModel` is still accessible.

   Example (untested):

   ```
   <SomeElementOutsideYourDataGrid Tag="{Binding TheModel}" />
   ...
       <Button>
           <Button.Visibility>
               <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource yourMultiValueConverter}">
                   <Binding Path="IsEditable" />
                   <Binding ElementName="SomeElementOutsideYourDataGrid" Path="Tag.IsAdmin"/>
               </MultiBinding>
           </Button.Visibility>
       </Button>
   ```
3. Use a more powerful binding framework such as [PyBinding](http://pybinding.codeplex.com/).

Comment: The example was a highly simplified version of the actual implementation which was already using a custom converter. Changing to an `IMultiValueConverter` and passing both did the trick. Thanks!